# I'm unable to play video on macOS ( OpenCV - Python)

Tags: python, opencv, video

there are no issues with writing the videos, but while reading the video, I can see the python file running in my dock but there is no window displaying the same, I tried with *'XVID',  *'DIVX' , *'mp4v', *'MJPG' codec formats and mp4 and avi files, I changed my default players on Mac between QuickTime, VLC and IINA, but its the same with all the cases, the python file is running with no error, but I don't see the window displaying the video, in fact I don't see any window

*in these 2 scripts, the files are different, but that's no mistake
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you see any frame in first script ? If yes, please add cv2.waitKey(n) - which n is greater than 0 - to second script.

Comment: @Wtow thank you, I just had to add the waitKey() function, if you have time, can you explain as to why this was happening, as per my understanding waitKey() had been used by me to only break out of the loop, and it does not have any connection with reading the file.

Comment: @ShivacharanReddy cv2.waitKey(n) is used to display an image in a window for given milliseconds or until any key is pressed, where n is time in millisecond. Without waitkey, you wont be able to see the frame in display window with imshow. We have to use imshow and waitkey combination in opencv to display the frame. If n in cv2.waitKey(n) is 0, then opencv waits till we press any key. If n > 0 is passed, opencv will wait for n milliseconds. Add cv2.namedWindow("name", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL) before the while loop,it will open a display window. And use the same "name" in imshow to display the frame.

Comment: @prabhakar-sivanesan ahh ok, thanks man. Really appreciate it.